# Dynamic Stylesheet based on Geolocation of visitor

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, geolocation

I'm currently trying to find a way to change the logo & color style of the website for my employer based on the Geolocation of the User.

Its an international group of companies, based in the Netherlands, which has a growing number of subsidaries over the world (for example in Russia and Brazil).

http://www.ipsgroupbv.com

The Russian and Portuguese translated sections of the website fall under the International Group (IPS Group), but we want only users from Russia (and the CIS) and Brazil/Portugal to see the logo of the designated subsidary companies. Instead of making a whole seperate website - i wanted to find a way to change the stylesheet based on Geolocation. This because only the colorscheme and logo changes, nothing else. In addition we also have registered domain names from the countries in question (i.e ipsgroupbv.com.br and ipsgroupbv.ru)

Our website is powered by wordpress and the WPML translation plugin.

Could anyone point me in the right direction to finding a sollution? I was thinking of a php or jQuery sollution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=your_ip_address` to get user location details.
You will json error like

```
{
  "geoplugin_request":"127.0.0.1",
  "geoplugin_status":404,
  "geoplugin_credit":"Some of .....",
  "geoplugin_city":"",
  "geoplugin_region":"",
  "geoplugin_areaCode":"",
  "geoplugin_dmaCode":"",
  "geoplugin_countryCode":"",
  "geoplugin_countryName":"",
  "geoplugin_continentCode":"",
  "geoplugin_latitude":"0",
  "geoplugin_longitude":"0",
  "geoplugin_regionCode":"",
  "geoplugin_regionName":null,
  "geoplugin_currencyCode":null,
  "geoplugin_currencySymbol":null,
  "geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8":"",
  "geoplugin_currencyConverter":0
}
```

pass your ip address and check it.
write php code according to country.